# Flex 3: Preventing keyboard events from reaching a Sprite

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, events, mxml

I'm working on a Flex 3 app, implemented in Actionscript 3 and MXML, that includes an embedded video player, which is essentially a black box--I load it as a SWF from another site on demand, and I don't have access to its source code. It does, however, inherit from Sprite.

The problem is that, when focus is on the Flash app, the video player is somehow receiving and processing keyboard events, even when the player itself isn't in focus. So when users are typing text elsewhere in the GUI, if they hit the space bar, the video pauses.

I've tried intercepting key events in the Sprite's parent, and setting tabEnabled = false, tabChildren = false, and buttonMode = false on the Sprite, but nothing seems to work. It's as if the Sprite is getting keystrokes through an alternate Event path.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I can prevent the player from receiving keyboard events or input events entirely? It's fine with me if no input events reach the player, since I've implemented my own, separate video controls.

Comment: By *"tried intercepting key events in the Sprite's parent"*, do you mean an event listener with [useCapture](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html#addEventListener()) set to true?

Comment: Shot in the dark and likely won't solve it, but another thing to at least try, `yourPlayer.focusRect = false;`

Comment: With regard to @wvxvw's comment if that is the case you can stop the propagation of the events in your input boxes by adding a listener for keyUp, then call event.stopImmediatePropagation() to stop the event from bubbling up to the stage (you would need to do this on all inputs which is obviously not ideal but it may work).  Also you can try setting a listener on the stage for keyUp with a maximum priority and hopefully it would be called before the one registered by the player, then follow the same stop propagation method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My first intuition is exactly what @wvxvw said.  The component you're using probably listens to events at the stage level.  I consider adding event listeners like this a horrible break in encapsulation principles, and it sounds like you've inherited the issue.

My attempt at solving it would be to cancel the events before they hit the stage.  Since you tagged this as Flex, in your main application add an event listeners for [keyUp](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3akeyUp) and [keyDown](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event%3akeyDown).

In the event listener, just check the target; and if it is not an instance of your video player, then [stop propogation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/Event.html#stopPropagation%28%29).

```
protected function keyUpListener(event:Event):void{
 if(event.target == myVideoPlayerInstance){
   return;
 }
 event.stopPropagation();
 event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}
```

Assuming your app does not have any other keyUp/keyDown event listeners added to the stage this approach should work (in theory).

If the video component you're using has events in the capture phase, I'm not sure if there is anything you can do to prevent it.

Comment: This fixed my problem and expanded my knowledge of the Flex event system. Thanks!